# aframe state component: bind-for does not update entities

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to render entities based on an array in the state:

```
[
  { id: 'left', color: 'red', position: '-1 1 -4' },
  { id: 'right', color: 'green', position: '1 1 -4' }
]
```

The entities are displayed successfully according to

```
<a-entity bind-for="for: marker; in: markers; key: id"> <!-- ; updateInPlace: true ?? -->
  <template>
    <a-sphere color="{{marker.color}}" position="{{marker.position}}"></a-sphere>
    <!-- <a-sphere bind-item__color="marker.color" bind-item__position="marker.position"></a-sphere> --><!-- state.marker is undefined -->
  </template>
</a-entity>
```

I cannot get the entities to update when I alter the array (adding or removing elements) or manually setting the __dirty flag.

```
handlers: {
  setMarkers: function (state, data) {
    state.markers.length = 0;
    state.markers.push(...data.markers);
  },
  updateMarkers: function (state, data) {
    state.markers.__dirty = true;
  }
}
```

Neither replacing the array elements nor setting the dirty flag works.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  markers[0].color = markers[0].color === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
  //el.sceneEl.emit('setMarkers', {markers});
  el.sceneEl.emit('updateMarkers', {});
});
```

Questions:

- how can I make the state component update the entities when an array (or its items) has been updated?
- when should I use `updateInPlace`?
- why cannot I use `bind-item__color="marker.color"`, as specified in the documentation? -- I get `state.marker is undefined`.

Glitch link: https://glitch.com/~aframe-state-bind-for-help

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Score</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Incrementing and decrementing score"></meta>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermedium/superframe/master/components/state/examples/score/preview.gif"></meta>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-state-component@6.7.0/dist/aframe-state-component.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
AFRAME.registerState({
  initialState: {
    markers: []
  },

  handlers: {
    setMarkers: function (state, data) {
      state.markers.length = 0;
      state.markers.push(...data.markers);
    },
    updateMarkers: function (state, data) {
      state.markers.__dirty = true;
    }
  }
});
      
      let markers = [
        { id: 'left', color: 'red', position: '-1 1 -4' },
        { id: 'right', color: 'green', position: '1 1 -4' }
      ];
      
      AFRAME.registerComponent('decrease-action', {
        init: function () {
          var el = this.el;
          el.addEventListener('click', function () {
            markers[0].color = markers[0].color === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
            //el.sceneEl.emit('setMarkers', {markers});
            el.sceneEl.emit('updateMarkers', {});
          });
          
          el.sceneEl.addEventListener('stateupdate', function (e) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e.detail.state.markers, null, 2));
          });
          
          el.sceneEl.emit('setMarkers', {markers});
        }
      });
      AFRAME.registerComponent('increase-action', {
        init: function () {
          var el = this.el;
          el.addEventListener('click', function () {
            markers[1].color = markers[1].color === 'green' ? 'blue' : 'green';
            //el.sceneEl.emit('setMarkers', {markers});
            el.sceneEl.emit('updateMarkers', {});
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity text="value: Change left color; align: center; width: 2" geometry="primitive: plane" material="color: black" position="-1 1 -3" decrease-action></a-entity>
      <a-entity text="value: Change right color; align: center; width: 2" geometry="primitive: plane" material="color: black" position="1 1 -3" increase-action></a-entity>
      
      <a-entity bind-for="for: marker; in: markers; key: id"> <!-- ; updateInPlace: true ?? -->
        <template>
          <a-sphere color="{{marker.color}}" position="{{marker.position}}"></a-sphere>
          <!-- <a-sphere bind-item__color="marker.color" bind-item__position="marker.position"></a-sphere> --><!-- state.marker is undefined -->
        </template>
      </a-entity>
      
      <a-sky color="#24CAFF"></a-sky>

      <a-camera>
        <a-cursor color="#FAFAFA"></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.